# JavaScript doesn't load in WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I've been working in a wordpress template lately, but i'm having a massive problem versus javascript in here.

I've tried:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('tools'); ?>
```

and

```
 <script src="/(path)/tools" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but the strange thing is that I simply put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello world");    
</script>
```

and it works just fine

Edit: I'm doing this in the header file

Comment: Is the path correct? (look at page source and click on the link and see if you actually open your js file). Also, maybe it's just a typo, but enclose the src url in quotes (src=".....")

Comment: I've cliked it, it redirects to the correct file, still it won't show on the page.

Comment: Do you get any errors on your console?

Comment: Well, it shows since you saw the `<script..></script>` and followed the link. If you mean that whatever you're after is not working, did you check in a JS console if there are any errors? (maybe compatibility with other libraries, or general errors)

Comment: I posted a solution that should work unless you have either some typos or a non-standard setup. If the below doesn't work post a link to a test site.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
But it is there...

Comment: Problem Solved, the problem has actualy in the JS files

Answer (score 0):

Before you enqueue a script you need to register it with: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

So you would have

```
wp_register_script("tools", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/myscript.js");
wp_enqueue_script("tools");
```

also remember to put any JS that should run after the DOM has loaded inside of either

```
$(document).ready(function() { //code here });
```

or

```
window.onload = function() { //code here }
```